# raspberry pi 2 booting steps with u-boot

Tags: linux-kernel, embedded-linux, raspberry-pi2, boot, u-boot

I am learning the boot process on rPi with u-boot. What are the steps (function calls) and file (.c and .S) that it goes from while booting the kernel up on rPi ?

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you provide U-Boot repository you are using for your RPi2? And also branch or tag or commit you are particularly interested in. And `defconfig` file you are using.

Comment: This is very vague and there are a number of articles and presentations on the general process of bringing a modern SoC out of power on reset and to the point of starting Linux.  Given that the source for U-Boot is also freely available, use the source and ask specific questions.

Comment: sorry for late reply, I was out of town. I am following https://blog.night-shade.org.uk/2015/05/booting-a-raspberry-pi2-with-u-boot-and-hyp-enabled/ .But i am wondering where to start from ....

Comment: After compilation, i have u-boot.map. can i traverse function call from that file ?